# Get the number of posts in a named category, outside the loop

Tags: categories

I've managed to do this from a `single.php` file, inside the loop, but now I need to do it from another page.

I need to find out how many live posts are in category named `every story` (slug is `everystory`). I am not inside the loop.

I just need the number, I don't need to output anything except the number. E.g `8`

I have tried searching for a way to gather category data just via the `category_name` (could be name, or could be slug, could even be by category `ID`) but everything I've found so far refers to using a specific `$post` var and finding it's category which isn't what I want to do.

Here is the example of what I used on the `single` post page:

```
$category = get_the_category();
$counter = $category[0]->category_count;
```

Comment: Exactly on which page/template

Comment: @PieterGoosen it's on a page template I have created. The page template outputs a query for some posts. But it shouldn't matter? Is there not a way to call the category data just from the category name/slug/

Comment: Jip, see my answer, it should work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm a bit unsure of you are actually asking, so apologies if I understood it wrong.

You can use [`get_category()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category) to get the category object and then just simply echo the `$count` property value

```
$cat_count = get_category( 'ID OR ROW OBJECT' );
echo $cat_count->count;
```